# executing a pattern in a case statement that matches two expressions

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
hw() {
        echo "hello world"
}

h0() {
        echo "hello w0r16"
}

h3w() {
        echo "h3ll0 world"
}

h30() {
        echo "h3110 w0rld"
}


read -p "enter 1 for hello and 2 for h3110: " hello
read -p "enter A for world and B for w0r16: " world1

option=$hello+$world1

case $option in 
    1+A|a) hw;;
    1+B|b) h0;;
    2+A|a) h3w;;
    2+B|b) h30;;
    5) echo "You have chosen to exit script" && exit 1;;
esac
```

how do i match both the inputs `hello` and `world1` to the case statement. so it can find the match.
example if i enter `1` for the first input and `a` for the second one. how do i match both inputs to find `hw` where the output would be `hello world`.

Comment: `1+A|a` means "`1+A` or `a`", not "`1+` (`A` or `a`)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use brackets to look for one of a set of characters:

```
$ foo=1; bar=B
$ option=$foo+$bar
$ case $option in 1+[bB]) echo 1b;; esac
1b
```

Alternation would apply to the whole pattern, i.e. `1+A|a` looks for either `1+A` or `a` but not `1+a`.

Though in this case, I would generate the "hello"/"h3ll0" and "world"/"w0r16" separately. You'd still have four cases total, but could save on duplication when generating the strings.

Comment: is there a way to loop the script?

Comment: @User10, probably, depends on what you're doing.

Comment: i mean like once the script outputs the result is there anyway to redo the script until the user enters the option to exit the script or enters an invalid character

Comment: @User10, wrap the whole thing in a loop, e.g. `while true; do read ...; case ... quit) break;; esac; done`. Or `exit` instead of `break`. That's a bit of a different question though.